# Read Preference In MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How we can set read preference for a particular query in MongoDB? Can anyone please share NodeJS example for MongoDB find and aggregate query with the use of read preference? We are using mongoose as an ODM.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html).

Possible options are:

- ReadPreference.PRIMARY
- ReadPreference.PRIMARY_PREFERRED
- ReadPreference.SECONDARY
- ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED
- ReadPreference.NEAREST

Sample code:

```
collection.find({}).setReadPreference(new ReadPreference(ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED)).toArray(function(err, items) {
  // Done reading from secondary if available
})
```